# Sentence tokenizer retrieve spans

Tags: python-3.x, nltk, tokenize

I want to retrieve the spans of the basic `ntlk` sentence tokenizer (I know it's doable using the pst tokenizer but the basic tokenizer is doing a better job). Is it possible to run the `span_tokenize` method on `sent_tokenize`?

```
from nltk import sent_tokenize
sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(text)
```

Comment: Do you want spans of words or spans of sentences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want spans of words.

```
from nltk.tokenize import WhitespaceTokenizer as wt
from nltk import sent_tokenize
sentences = sent_tokenize("This is a sentence. This is another sentence. The sky is blue.")
print(list(wt().span_tokenize_sents(sentences)))
```

output:

```
[[(0, 4), (5, 7), (8, 9), (10, 19)], [(0, 4), (5, 7), (8, 15), (16, 25)], [(0, 3), (4, 7), (8, 10), (11, 16)]]
```

See https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html. Search for span_tokenize_sents.

Comment: I intended spans of sentences, sorry about the misleading post

Answer (score 3):

For sentence spans, you could use `span_tokenize()` from `nltk.tokenize.punkt.PunktSentenceTokenizer`: https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html#nltk.tokenize.punkt.PunktSentenceTokenizer.

The following code

```
    from nltk.tokenize.punkt import PunktSentenceTokenizer as pt
    full_text = "This is your text. You will split it into sentences. And get their spans."
    spans = list(pt().span_tokenize(full_text))
    print(spans)
```

will give you the output:

```
[(0, 18), (19, 52), (53, 73)]
```